# Findby DateTime the recent uploaded articles Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, posts, findby

Hello im triying to get on my dashboard only the most recent articles
but isnt working i did this function

```
public function PostsRecientes(){
    return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('        
    SELECT post
    FROM App:Posts post 
    WHERE post.fechaPublicacion > CURRENT_DATE()')
    ->getResult();
}
```

and this in my dashboardcontroller

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="dashboard")
 */
public function index(PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request): Response
{
    
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $posts = $em->getRepository(Posts::class)->PostsRecientes();
    return $this->render('dashboard/index.html.twig', [
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

but when i do a var dump i doesnt bring any post.

Comment: Can `post.fechaPublicacion` really contain dates in the future? Because that's what your query is specifying.

Comment: i think so i got this     $this->fechaPublicacion = new \DateTime(); in my Post.php im newbie in this so im not really sure

Comment: That means any time a post is created it sets the current time. So, you can't have dates in the future. The answer that @hous posted should cover your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`, for example:

```
public function PostsRecientes()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults(6);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```